# R loop opening files

Tags: r

I am trying to run a simple 5 lines command but over 9000 different files. I wrote the following for loop

```
setwd("/Users/morandin/Desktop/Test")
output_file<- ("output_file.txt")
files <- list.files("/Users/morandin/Desktop/Test")
for(i in files) {
  chem.w.in <- scan(i, sep=",")
  pruned.tree<-drop.tip(mytree,which(chem.w.in %in% NA))  
  plot(pruned.tree)
  pruned.tree.ja.chem.w.in <- phylo4d(pruned.tree, c(na.omit(chem.w.in)))
  plot(pruned.tree.ja.chem.w.in) 
  out <- abouheif.moran(pruned.tree.ja.chem.w.in)
  print(out)
}
```

Hey I am editing my question: the above code does the for loop perfectly now (thanks for all your help). I am still having an issue with the output.

I can redirect the entire output using R through bash commands but I would need the name of the processed file. My output looks like this:

```
class: krandtest 
Monte-Carlo tests
Call: as.krandtest(sim = matrix(res$result, ncol = nvar, byrow = TRUE), 
    obs = res$obs, alter = alter, names = test.names)

Number of tests:   1 

Adjustment method for multiple comparisons:   none 
Permutation number:   999 
  Test       Obs   Std.Obs   Alter Pvalue
1   dt 0.1458514 0.7976225 greater    0.2

other elements: adj.method call
```

Is there a way to print Pvalue results and name of the file (element i)??

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need a `.` between the file name and the file extension? What does `files` look like?  Try changing it to `paste(i, "txt", sep = ".")` But they should probably have extensions already when they come from `list.files`

Comment: you can just write `read.table(i)` in your loop

Comment: @koundy assuming that the current working directory is `/Users/morandin/Desktop/Test`. By default `list.files()` does not return a full path.

Comment: @Paul absolutely you are right. I missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Paul Hiemstra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26751936/2954547) answered #1, here's an answer to #2, assuming that by "answers" you mean "the printed output of  `abouheif.moran(pruned.tree.ja.chem.w.in)`".

Use `cat()` with the argument `append = true`. For example:

```
output_file = "my_output_file.txt"
for(i in files) {
    # do stuff
    # make plots
    out <- abouheif.moran(pruned.tree.ja.chem.w.in)
    out <- sprintf("-------\n  %s:\n-------\n%s\n\n", i, out)
    cat(out, file = output_file, append = TRUE)
}
```

This will produce a file called `my_output_file.txt` that looks like:

```
-------
file_1:
-------
output_goes_here

-------
file_2:
-------
output_goes_here
```

Obviously the formatting is entirely up to you; I just wanted to demonstrate what could be done here.

An alternative solution would be to `sink()` the entire script, but I'd rather be explicit about it. A middle road might be to `sink()` just a small piece of the code, but except in extreme cases it's a matter of preference or style.

Comment: If the data allows it, I think putting the results of the loop in a `data.frame` and saving that using `write.table` is the best way. This makes it much easier to read into R later, or into any other tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually transformed your sprintf function to get only the Pvalue and somehow managed!

Comment: @user3188922 In that case I'd recommend taking the `write.table` approach for portability

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what is going wrong here is that `list.files()` by default returns a list of only the names of the files, not the entire path to the file. Setting `full.names` to `TRUE` will fix this issue. Note that you will not have to add the `txt` add the filename as `list.files()` already returns the full path to an existing file.

Comment: For completeness: `(Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection)` is just an ugly way of saying "`file` not found".